# dynamodb: how to filter all items which do not have a certain attribute?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table of users with a primary hash key of userId. each user may/may not have a string attribute called "environment".
I would like to get all the users which have "environment"="xyz" or which do not have the "environment" attribute.

The following code will filter those users with environment=xyz, but how do I filter those items with no environment at all? Dynamo API will not allow to filter on an empty String.

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = DbClientManager.getDynamoDbClient();

    ArrayList<AttributeValue> avList = new ArrayList<AttributeValue>();
    avList.add(new AttributeValue().withS("xyz"));

    Condition scanFilterCondition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(avList);
    Map<String, Condition> conditions = new HashMap<>();
    conditions.put("environment", scanFilterCondition);

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("users")
            .withAttributesToGet(
                    "userId", 
                    "environment");
            .withScanFilter(conditions);

    ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
```

For now I just dropped the scan filter, and I do the filtering client-side. Bit is there any way to do it server side?

Thanks,
Aliza

Answer (score 7):

Hope I'm not too late.
I've found useful function which you could use in the query. I did not check with ScanRequest but with QueryRequest works as charm.

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
            .withTableName("YouTableName")
    queryRequest.setFilterExpression(" attribute_not_exists(yourAttributeName) ")
    queryRequest.setExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
    queryRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(ifYouHave)
    queryRequest.setSelect('ALL_ATTRIBUTES')
    queryRequest.setExpressionAttributeNames(youNames)
```

attribute_not_exists(yourAttributeName) works with ":aws-sdk:1.11.11"
also you could use attribute_exists(yourAttributeName)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `NULL` ComparisonOperator.

Check out this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

- NOT_NULL : The attribute exists.
- NULL : The attribute does not exist.

Does this work for you?

Comment: This does not work since I want 2 conditions (with logical OR) on the same attribute. When I put my conditions in the Map<String, Condition> structure, the second condition overwrite the first (since they have the same key). I can either filter environment=xyz or environment=NULL but not both together.

Comment: I understand... I looked around and I cannot find a way to do this. The only suggestion that I can give is to post this to the Amazon DynamoDB forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131. I have posted there in the past and someone from Amazon did reply to me. Your question has additional complexity than this one, for example, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=341426&#341426, because you also need to handle the lack of the `environment` attribute. Good luck with your search!

Answer (score 0):

I my case also, attribute_not_exists(attribute) worked. You can refer to this question:- [How to check whether an attribute is not present in dynamoDB filter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209795/how-to-check-whether-an-attribute-is-not-present-in-dynamodb-filter-expression)

for more details.