# How to check whether an attribute is not present in dynamoDB filter expression

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am introducing a new field InActive in my dynamo DB table, now I want to fetch the records which were active earlier (assuming all previous records were active) along with new Active records.

What should be my dynamo DB Query expression?

```
final HashMap<String, AttributeValue> activeExpressionAttrValue = new HashMap<>();
    activeExpressionAttrValue.put(":in_active_false", new AttributeValue().withBOOL(false));
    activeExpressionAttrValue.put(":in_active_null", new AttributeValue().withNULL(true));


 dynamoDBQueryExpression.withHashKeyValues(ddbRecord.builder().primarykey(p).build())
            .withFilterExpression(ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + " = :in_active_false OR" +
                    ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + " = :in_active_null")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(activeExpressionAttrValue);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

```
 ... ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + " = :in_active OR attribute_not_exists(" + ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + ")" ...
```

DynamoDb doesn't perform implicit conversion to null. For above query to work the data in table would have to contain:

```
 {
     "some_attribute": {
          "S": "some attribute string value"
     },
     "is_active": {
          "NULL":true
     }
 }
```

However, I suspect, that old records in table simply do not contain "is_active" attribute rather than having it present and set to NULL hence valid condition is **attribute_not_exists(is_active)**

Comment: what is the difference in ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + " = :in_active_null" and attribute_not_exists(" + ddbRecord.IN_ACTIVE + ")"  ?

Comment: yes, I ran the query, it is not giving any output in this case. means the already active records are also not coming.

Comment: In your example you added values for **:in_active_null** that will fail as I described above  and value for **:in_active_false** while your query is looking for **:in_active** (without _false)

Comment: that was wrongly described in question. I used in_active_false only.

Comment: And, what does **ddbRecord.builder().primarykey(p).build()** return? You should set HashKey only. If it adds some stray value for RangeKey you're query will be limited to at most 1 record only.

Comment: Yes this is the hashkey for my table to identify the record and further the record has to be fetched only if it is active or does not have the in_active field present as this is the newly added field.

Comment: Thanks @Andrzej, the expression attribute_not_exists(is_active) worked for me!